# Counting changes in timeline with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I need your help. I have a table with similar data

```
---------------------------------------------------
|RobotPosX|RobotPosY|RobotPosDir|RobotShortestPath|
---------------------------------------------------
|0.1      |   0.2   |      15   |       1456      |
|0.2      |   0.3   |      30   |       1456      |
|0.54     |   0.67  |      15   |       1456      |
|0.68     |   0.98  |      22   |       1234      |
|0.36     |   0.65  |      45   |       1234      |
|0.65     |   0.57  |      68   |       1456      |
|0.65     |   0.57  |      68   |       2556      |
|0.79     |   0.86  |      90   |       1456      |                 
---------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see there are repeated values in the column RobotShortestPath, But they are important. Each number represent a specific task. If the number repeats consecutively(ex: 1456), it means that Robot is performing that task, and when the number changes(ex: 1234) it means that it has switched to another task. And if the previous number(ex:1456) appears again it also means that robot is performing a new task(1456) after done with earlier task(1234).

So where I am stuck is I am unable to get no of tasks performed. I have used several things from my minimum knowledge like COUNT, GROUP BY but nothing seem to work.

Here the no.of tasks performed are 5 actually, but whatever I do I get only 3 as result.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename` ?

Comment: What is the output of the result you want?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But that would return total no.of entries in the table.

Comment: @JonasT Hello Jonas, I want the result to be 5 as the total number of tasks performed are 5 even they are repeated. Thank You!!

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for [samples](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: Please update the question with the desired result for the given sample data (which is what Jonas was asking about). In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET @last_task = 0;
SELECT SUM(new_task) AS tasks_performed
FROM (
  SELECT 
    IF(@last_task = RobotShortestPath, 0, 1) AS new_task,
    @last_task := RobotShortestPath
  FROM table
  ORDER BY ??
) AS tmp
```

**Update for multiple tables**
From a database strcture normailization view, your better of with one table, and have a filed identifing what column is what robot, if that not posible for some reason, you can get that by union the tables:

```
SET @last_task = 0;
SELECT robot_id, SUM(new_task) AS tasks_performed
FROM (
  SELECT 
    IF(@last_task = RobotShortestPath, 0, 1) AS new_task,
    @last_task := RobotShortestPath
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS robot_id, robot_log_1.* FROM robot_log_1
    UNION SELECT 2, robot_log_2.* FROM robot_log_2
    UNION SELECT 3, robot_log_3.* FROM robot_log_3
    UNION SELECT 4, robot_log_4.* FROM robot_log_4
    UNION SELECT 5, robot_log_5.* FROM robot_log_5
  ) as robot_log
  ORDER BY robot_id, robot_log_id
) AS robot_log_history
GROUP BY robot_id
ORDER BY tasks_performed DESC
```

Comment: no result? i tried it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e80f5/3 but i get 4 insted of 5, hmm, but if i run http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e80f5/4 thers 5 rows with new_task = 1

Comment: @PugganSe Hello Puggan, just FYI I am using HeidiSql UI for MySQL.

Comment: the sqlfiddle was buggy, the code works fine, got that verifed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577333/why-is-the-sum-of-five-1-4/11577453, what error message did you get insted of results?

Comment: It just returns nothing,

/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 2 queries: 0.000 sec. */

Comment: Hello Puggan, MySQL workbench returns the perfect result. But somehow HeidiSQL returns nothing. Thanks a lot Puggan.

Comment: @PugganSe Hello Puggan, I have another small doubt.

Suppose if I have used this query for 5 tables and I have the results. How to choose the highest of all and may be show it in a text box in Visual Studio.

Comment: why do you have 5 tables like this? that dosn't sound normalized

Comment: @PugganSe 5 tables for 5 different robots. I work with Humanoids and develop applications for them using C#. My new project is to work with DB of robots. So I am new to MySQL and Stuff. I was able to do some basic search functions using basic level queries. But this is a bit complex for me.

Comment: the upated part of the answer gives you a "highscore" list of the 5 robots from 5 tables of robot logs

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14177/discussion-between-chaitanya-krishna-and-puggan-se)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need to track when `RobotShortestPath` is changed to another value. To achieve this you can use [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html) like this:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER track AFTER UPDATE ON yourtable
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.RobotShortestPath != OLD.RobotShortestPath THEN
      UPDATE tracktable SET counter=counter+1 WHERE tracker=1;
    END IF;
  END;
|

delimeter ;
```

Comment: Hello Timur, But How could I get a result i.e., the total no of tasks???

Thank You!!!

Comment: @BommareddyChaitanyaKrishna result will be stored in another table. See `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I get the following error:

SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' */

Comment: So, you previously created some trigger on this table? Also, I think I understood you the wrong way and you need to to track changes but to track new records

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I couldn't find this another table.

Comment: Hello Timur,

I created no triggers before. I don't have that knowledge yet. What I want is How many tasks are performed that is how many time the column value has changed which reflects the no of tasks.

Thank You!!!

Comment: Thank you Timur for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
set @n:=0, @i:=0;
select max(sno) from
(
select @n:=case when @i=RobotShortestPath then @n else @n+1 end as sno, 
@i:=RobotShortestPath as dno
from table 
) as t;
```

Comment: Hello Madhavinan, the problem was with HeidiSql, Your query returns perfect result in MySQL workbench. Thank You Very Much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
SET @cnt = 0, @r = -1;

SELECT IF(armed <> @r, @cnt:= @cnt + 1, 0), @r:= RobotShortestPath, @cnt FROM table;

SELECT @cnt AS count;
```

Comment: I have tested it on MySQL 5.5 and its working perfect. Check testing same query from different tool.